# Nav in the Bottom inside a NavBar using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys not sure if my title is right but i'm new to bootstrap and i am trying out the navbar loving it so far but i'm stuck trying to accomplish this

[image]

what i want is for my items inside my ul bar marked in yellow to be in the bottom where i marked also in yellow, is there any class i can use for this or do i have to add my own CSS class to do this?

here is my html code

```
 <div class ="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="default.aspx" class = "brand"><img alt ="Imagen no disponible" src ="Img/Aralogo.png" /></a>
        <div class ="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href ="#"><h4> Compañia </h4></a> </li>
            <li><a href ="#"><h4> Nomina </h4></a></li>
            <li><a href ="#"><h4> Inventario </h4></a></li>
            <li><a href ="#"><h4> Planificacion</h4></a></li>
            <li><a href ="#"><h4> Reportes </h4></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...if you want those navbar links moved down, you could just rewrite the padding style for them. Applying this style after the Twitter Bootstrap styles have been applied will achieve what I believe you're looking for:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding: 20px 15px 0;
}
```

If that isn't low enough for you, you could alter the h4 element as well, with:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a > h4{
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
```

(And if that's too low, you could change the 20px to some lower number.)

I hope this helps you out. It can be tricky sometimes to get what you want with a CSS framework if it falls outside of the basic design, but keep at it! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently.
Just add an additional container around the brand element

```
<div class="container">
<a href="default.aspx" class = "brand"><img alt ="Imagen no disponible" src ="Img/Aralogo.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: im not sure if i did it right but adding this , the result was this http://s13.postimg.org/tbp3fwqrr/Captura2.png not really what i was looking for